# VS xamarin phone emulator wont turn on

Tags: c#, xamarin, emulation

I am making an android application on xamarin VS 2019.
I tried using different VS emulators. When I debug, the phone loads and I can rotate it but when I try to turn it on it does not work. It says that System UI won't turn on and at other times it says that the process failed. I cannot figure out why, I did exactly the same as the tutorial.

Comment: Did you enable virtualization technologies to accelerate the Android emulator? If not, please refer to this thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

Comment: You can share information in the Output window here,  It will have some errors or exceptions.